# SVN Path-Based Authorization Error When Adding Branches

Tags: svn, repository, authorization

I have modified my authz file on my SVN server to enable path-based authorization. I'm running into an issue when specifying the authorization settings for a branch within a repository. Here is what my authz file looks like:

```
[aliases]
# joe = /C=XZ/ST=Dessert/L=Snake City/O=Snake Oil, Ltd./OU=Research Institute/CN=Joe Average

[groups]
firmware_team = eddie,jackson
contractors = frank,max

# Provide default access here for entire repository
[/]
* =
@firmware_team = rw

# Define access here for the myrepo repository
[myrepo:/]
@contractors = r

[myrepo:/branches/contractor_branch/]
@contractors = rw
```

So, by default I am providing everyone with read-only access to my repositories while also providing default read/write access to the `firmware_team` group.

The problem here is that the firmware_team group becomes forbidden to commit to the `myrepo` trunk when I add these lines enabling authorization for a specific branch of the repository:

```
[myrepo:/branches/contractor_branch/]
@contractors = rw
```

If I comment out these lines like so:

```
# [myrepo:/branches/contractor_branch/]
# @contractors = rw
```

Then the firmware team is allowed to access the trunk again. I'm not sure why this happens, could someone enlighten me?

One thing I did find interesting though in the SVN Book is this line:

> Permissions for group members can only be extended beyond the
>   permissions the group already has. Restricting users who are part of a
>   group to less than their group's permissions is impossible.

This made me think that if I am giving a group read/write access to the entire repo, then simply adding specific authorization to a branch of that repo should not cause a group to lose access to said repos trunk.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue I was having. When specifying a path based repository authorization, you must omit the slash at the end of the repo. So for example:

This:

```
[myrepo:/branches/contractor_branch/]
@contractors = rw
```

Should be set like this:

```
[myrepo:/branches/contractor_branch]
@contractors = rw
```

Oddly enough, this only applies to anything other than the root of the repository. So this:

```
[myrepo:/]
@contractors = r
```

is still valid, since it points to the root.